# Javascript fetching data and parse them on a Variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch

I've been searching for a solution for my Problem, it seems actually pretty easy but it doesn't work :(. The problem is the following: I fetch data from my backend which is `localhost/users`. I get the data and i can console.log them. But it seems impossible for me to write it on a variable and export it. Here is my Code:

```
import axios from "axios";


function init() {
    let obj;
    axios('/users')
    .then(response => {
        obj = (response.data)
        console.log(obj)
        return obj
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("error fetching")
        return null
    })
    
}

let obj = init()


export default obj
```

If i try to console.log the exported variable it just writes undefined, i guess it skips the response section. The returned Variable is undefined too

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the value from the inner function.

To do that you can use `Promises` or `Callback` or simply React `setState` if you want to but it inside the component.

### Using Promises:

```js
import axios from "axios";


function init() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     axios('/users')
      .then(response => {
        obj = (response.data)
        resolve(obj);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      })
   });
}

// To log or get the values 
init().then(obj => {
  console.log(obj);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));


export default obj
```

### Using Callbacks

```js
import axios from "axios";


function init(successCallback, errorCallback) {
     axios('/users')
      .then(response => {
        obj = (response.data)
        successCallback(obj);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        errorCallback(error);
      })
}

// To log or get the values 
init(obj => {
  console.log(obj);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});


export default obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add return keyword before axios function

````
import axios from "axios";


function init() {
 let obj;
 return axios('/users')
 .then(response => {
     obj = (response.data)
     console.log(obj)
     return obj
 })
 .catch(error => {
     console.log("error fetching")
     return null
 })
 
}

let obj = init()


export default obj
 ```
````